# German date notation in paragraphs

Tags: horizontal-alignment, german, isodate

According to the DIN ISO 8601 a German date needs to be formated without a linebreak between in it.
So LaTeX have to break before or after the date.
Instead sometimes a date exceeds the linewidth.

See the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[ngerman]{isodate}
\numdate
\overfullrule=3pt

\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefgh \printdate{16.09.2014} abcdefg hijklmnop
\end{document}
```

How to handle this issue, that the date isn't exceeding?

Comment: You can rephrase the sentence and use the date at the beginning ...

Comment: Yes I could. But not when I have to adopt the phrases from somebody else.

Answer (score 2):

If you write a whole line with only two words, what should TeX do?

Solution for daily usage: `\usepackage{microtype}`.

Comment: This was just a MWE.
For sure: the real document is normal native language with more than 2 words. Thanks, I'll take a look on the package

Answer (score 2):

I suggest that you enclose the offending paragraph in a `sloppypar`environment, *i.e.*

Your MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[ngerman]{isodate}
\numdate
\overfullrule=3pt


\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{sloppypar}
abcdefghijklmnop qrstuvwxyzabcdefg hijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefgh \printdate{16.09.2014} abcdefg hijklmnop
\end{sloppypar}
\end{document}
```

Of course, in your example, you will have an awfull linebreaking due to lack of possible breakpoint in the example. In real text, where the lines are compose of several words, and using `microtype`, that will normally not be a big problem, but be prepared to edit the text (if you are authorised) to avoid such consequences.

I suggest you start using `microtype`and in the absolutely last touch up of the document (the final, final final version), you use `sloppypar` only if nothing else you are allowed to do, works.

Comment: I tried your given MWE and also adopted the sentence to native language (so more than 2 words). Actually doesn't change anything.

Comment: @RafaelWörner I misunderstood your question. See my revised answer.